# How to emit utf8 message in solidity

Tags: utf-8, solidity

How to emit utf8 message (such as Chinese) in the code below?

```
   pragma solidity ^0.7.2;
   modifier buyerOnly() {
    require(
        msg.sender == buyer,
        "For buyer ONLY"  //<<==utf8?
    );
```

It throws error with Chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to insert unicode characters into a string.

Disclaimer: I don't know Chinese, but I used Google Translate to convert "For buyer only" to Chinese simplified as this: 仅适用于买方 .  Then I used [an online tool](https://onlineunicodetools.com/escape-unicode) to convert this string into \U and \x escape sequences below.

Per solidity docs for string encoding of literals:

> \xNN takes a hex value and inserts the appropriate byte, while \uNNNN takes a Unicode codepoint and inserts an UTF-8 sequence.

So instead of trying this:

```
modifier buyerOnly() {
 require(
     msg.sender == buyer,
     "For buyer ONLY"  //<<==utf8?
 );
```

This (the UTF-16 escapes will get converted back to UTF-8)

```
modifier buyerOnly() {
 require(
     msg.sender == buyer,
     "\u4ec5\u9002\u7528\u4e8e\u4e70\u65b9"
 );
```

Or this (insert UTF-8 bytes individually):

```
modifier buyerOnly() {
 require(
     msg.sender == buyer,
     "\xe4\xbb\x85\xe9\x80\x82\xe7\x94\xa8\xe4\xba\x8e\xe4\xb9\xb0\xe6\x96\xb9"
 );
```

Comment: There is no error after entering either UTF8/16 translation! There are 2 option for UTF16 and none of them produces the same output (longer and more chars) as yours. How did you get the UTF16?

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyword `unicode""`

Example: `string public saudacao = unicode"Olá sou uma variável ";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`string public saudacao = unicode"Olá sou uma variável";`